# Is it possible to make a HTTP (POST) request without waiting for a response, in either Java or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, asynchronous

I need to create a http post request without waiting for a response in either Java or JavaScript. Async http calls is not what I’m looking for as it still waits for a response, just on a separate thread.

Comment: Isn't just leaving out a `load` listener (`XMLHttpRequest`) or a `.then` (`Fetch`) enough?

Comment: "as it still waits for a response". Whatever you use, you always have to wait for a HTTP response.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/8612364/9727047

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible if you create your own connection send whatever you need and just kill the connection after.  The answer by Alan Geleynse from [Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily) does that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this post might help you.

Depending on what client you are using, you should be able to just invoke the post method(). I could be wrong but I believe adding the .then() is what makes it asynchronous.

[Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

yes, it possible, 
i was done it before when i working with laravel and i need lots of webhook send to merchans. before i write login waiting for response but it's take more time then i google and find the solution.
here is example.

```
function postCurlRequest(string $url, array $post_array, $check_ssl=true) {
    // $url = 'https://post_url.com';
    $cmd = "curl -L -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'";
    $cmd.= " -d '" . json_encode($post_array) . "' '" . $url . "'";

    if (!$check_ssl){
      $cmd.= "'  --insecure"; // this can speed things up, though it's not secure
    }
    $cmd .= " > /dev/null 2>&1 &"; // don't wait for response

    // echo $cmd;die;

    exec($cmd, $output, $exit);
   return $exit == 0;
}
```